# Multiple git editors

Tags: git, text-editor

Is it possible to have different editors configured for different git commands?

Say

- git commit => nano
- git rebase -i => sublime text

Or is there possibly some scripts that could act as an intermediator and analyse what kind of command I executed and then pen my desired editor?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `core.editor` and `sequence.editor` settings. `core.editor` will be used for committing, and `sequence.editor` will be used for interactive rebasing:

```
git config --global core.editor nano
git config --global sequence.editor <path to sublime text>
```

From the [official Linux Kernel Git documentation for `git config`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html):

> ```
> core.editor
> ```
>
> Commands such as commit and tag that lets you edit messages by launching an editor uses the value of this variable when it is set, and the environment variable GIT_EDITOR is not set. See [git-var(1)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-var.html).
>
> ```
> sequence.editor
> ```
>
> Text editor used by `git rebase -i` for editing the rebase insn file. The value is meant to be interpreted by the shell when it is used. It can be overridden by the GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR environment variable. When not configured the default commit message editor is used instead.